# animated slide tab using react

Tags: html, css

I'm making a simple tab:
https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-hill-fo60bu

The logic is very simple just add and remove class base on state

```
<div className={`selector ${tab === "two" ? "right" : "left"}`}></div>
```

but how possible is it for me to turn it into something like this?
https://codepen.io/Kapilnemo/pen/pbEbQy

where the selected bar have a 'slide' animation?

Comment: Here is an example of using [framer-motion](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-tabs-tjow1?file=/src/Tabs.js)

Answer (score 0):

It is in 57 and 59 line of codepen:

```
 -webkit-transition: margin 0.5s ease;
  
  transition: margin 0.5s ease;
```

Those lines are creating that "slide" animation.